# Calling a String With Cell Name Comes Empty but if I Use a String Directly it Works

Tags: regex, vba, excel

If I call a value like this it works:

```
=GetElementByRegex(D2;"<a href=""/StatWeb/Field/Index/15"">(.*?)</a>")
```

but if I call it with cell name, like this, it doesn't:

`=GetElementByRegex(D2;L2)` `(L2 is "<a href=""/StatWeb/Field/Index/15"">(.*?)</a>")`

it returns empty value....

or is there maybe an alternative where i can just replace index number (Index/15) with a cell name (F4 for example).

Im new at this.

The code i'm using behind is this one.

```
Public Function GetElementByRegex(url As String, reg As String)
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResult As Object
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regEx.Pattern = reg
    regEx.Global = True
    If regEx.Test(XMLHTTP.ResponseText) Then
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(XMLHTTP.ResponseText)
        GetElementByRegex = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        Exit Function
    End If
    GetElementByRegex = ""
End Function
```

Comment: Try it as L2 being `<a href="/StatWeb/Field/Index/15">(.*?)</a>` . It's a string literal, not a quoted string.

Comment: tnx. it works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the `"` in the range, it doubles them, to present a string. See the screenshot:

[image]

Thus, remove them and it should work.